# Trying to get the size of a .txt in Python

Tags: python, lines

So im trying to get the amount of lines in a .txt file in python. My file has 62 lines, but my programm tells me, that it has 184 lines.

```
import os
lines = os.path.getsize("file.txt")
print lines
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Hvae you read the documentation for [`os.path.getsize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) ?

Comment: Why did you think `getsize` would be a line count?!

Answer (score 1):

you should do it this way, if you want to count number of lines:

```
def wc(filename):
    """
    counts # of lines in a file (Like UNIX's [wc -l])
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return sum(1 for l in f)

lines = wc('file.txt')
```

in your code you are reading the size of your file in bytes

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) states:

> `os.path.getsize(path)`
>
> Return the size, in bytes, of *path*. Raise [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#OSError) if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

Use a different method, such as opening the file and iterating over it:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print sum(1 for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OSX or Linux and depending on your purpose, it may be much simpler for you to just open your terminal and type:

```
wc -l "filename"
```

wc is word count, adding the -l changes it to a line count.